# Access Denied to view tensorboard

Tags: tensorboard

I have tried some [tensorboard demo](https://github.com/MorvanZhou/Tensorflow-Tutorial/blob/master/tutorial-contents/305_tensorboard.py). The code runs fine, and after I ran `tensorboard --logdir log/`, I got the following console output which indicates everything is good so far:

```
(dlnd-tf-lab)  ->tensorboard --logdir log/
Starting TensorBoard b'47' at http://0.0.0.0:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, when I copy and paste 'http://0.0.0.0:6006' onto google chrome, I got the following message on the webpage:

```
Access Denied

You are not allowed to access this page.
```

Where did I get wrong? Could anyone help me here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

thanks to Morvan Zhou at https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials

solution: 
instead of `http://0.0.0.0:6006`, use `localhost:6006` and it works.